# How can I buy mETH in my mantle-network Metamask wallet? I bridged some ETH today but only ended up with wETH in my metamask

Tags: bridge, wrapped-tokens

I'm new to this. I ended up with wETH in my metamask. I'm trying to get mETH instead. How do I swap wETH for mETH?